# django - nginx+fastcgi --> Unhandled Exception (after upgrade from Django 1.2.4 to Django 1.3)

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi, django-settings, mod-fastcgi

I just upgraded from django 1.2.4 to 1.3.

I'm using **nginx** in conjunction with **fastcgi** and for some reason every time when I access a page I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: could you add a pastebin to your error.log, and maybe config files.

Comment: @ashwoods I found something in the  /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Middleware module "%s" does not define a "%s" class' % (mw_module, mw_classname))
ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.middleware.http" does not define a "SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor" class" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.1, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:1234", host: "mysite.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it I added this class (that practically doesn't do anything) in the : `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/http.py`

```
class SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor(object):
    """
    This middleware has been removed; see the Django 1.1 release notes for
    details.

    It previously set REMOTE_ADDR based on HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. However, after
    investiagtion, it turns out this is impossible to do in a general manner:
    different proxies treat the X-Forwarded-For header differently. Thus, a
    built-in middleware can lead to application-level security problems, and so
    this was removed in Django 1.1

    """
    def __init__(self):
        import warnings
        warnings.warn("SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor has been removed. "
                      "See the Django 1.1 release notes for details.",
                      category=DeprecationWarning)
        raise MiddlewareNotUsed()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to track down your fastcgi error log.  There should me more detailed information in there.

Comment: I'm not sure if fastcgi has a error log but I looked under /var/log/nginx/error.log and didn't find anything.